# My form won't submit and gives me an error (PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an admin panel and I have a form that should insert into the database, however I keep getting this error: إضافة الفيلم Duplicate entry '' for key 'title'..

P.s: if you cannot read some of this, it is because it is written in Arabic, please ask me if you don't know what it says.

Here is the code for the whole page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('php/config.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css" />
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Admin Panel v1.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if($_SESSION['username'] = false){
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/'); 
}
//this form allows to choose what to do (e.g. add new movie= ""...
else{
echo'

<ul class="management-b">
<li><a href="#">إضافة فيلم جديد</a></li>
<li><a href="#">إضافة مسلسل جديد</a></li>
<li><a href="#">مسح فيلم/مسلسل</a></li>
</ul>
';
}
?>
<form id="new-movie" method="post">
<input type="text" class="nM-title" name="nM-title" placeholder="عنوان الفيلم" /><br/><br/>
<textarea class="nM-desc" name="nM-desc" placeholder="وصف الفيلم"></textarea><br/><br/>
<?php
connectDB();
$genreSelect = mysql_query("SELECT genre FROM Genres");
?>
<select name="nM-genre" class="nM-genre">
<option default>نوع الفيلم</option>
<?php
while($genreOption = mysql_fetch_array($genreSelect)){
    echo '<option>'.$genreOption['genre'].'</option>';
    }
    closeDB();
?>
</select><br/><br/>
<select class="nM-year" name="nM-year">
<option>تاريخ إصدار الفيلم</option>
<?php
for($rYear = 1995; $rYear<2020; $rYear++){
echo '<option>'.$rYear.'</option>'; 
}
?>
</select><br/><br/>
<input type="text" class="nM-URL" name="nM-URL" placeholder="رابط الفيلم" /><br/><br/>
<input type="text" class="nM-IMG" name="nM-IMG" placeholder="صورة الفيلم" /><br/><br/>
<input type="textu" name="nM-IMDB" class="nM-IMDB" placeholder="IMDB" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="nM-submit" class="nM-submit" value="إضافة الفيلم" />

<?php
if($_POST['nM-submit']){

//these should be filled before submitted..
$checkTitle = $_POST['nM-title'];
$checkDesc = $_POST['nM-desc'];
$checkURL = $_POST['nM-URL'];
$checkIMG = $_POST['nM-IMG'];
$checkIMDB = $_POST['nM-IMDB'];
//these should be inserted to the database..
$mNID = rand(1000, 10000);
$mNTitle = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['nM-title']));
$mNDesc = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['nM-desc']));
$mNGenre = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['nM-genre']));
$mNYear = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['nM-year']));
$mNURL = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['nM-URL']));
$mNIMG = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['nM-IMG']));
$mNIMDB = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['nM-IMDB']));

if(empty($checkTitle) && empty($checkDesc) && empty($checkURL) && empty($checkIMG) && empty($checkIMDB)){
echo '<h1 class="nMError">لم تملأ جميع الخيارات</h1>';  
}
else{
    connectDB();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Movies(ID, title, description, genre, url, image, imdb, release_year) VALUES('$mNID', '$mNTitle', '$mNDesc', '$mNGenre', '$mNURL', '$mNIMG', '$mNIMDB', '$mNYear')") or die(mysql_error());
closeDB();

}
}
?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate entry '' for key 'title'..  *use a unique title* for **insert** or use **update** statement in sql

Comment: Avoid using `mysql_*` queries

Comment: Are you using the title column as the `primary key` ?

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all; it looks like you don't have a database connection when you use `mysql_real_escape_string()` so I'd expect all your variables to be empty. Which is probably the cause of your error but that's hard to tell without being able to read the complete error message...

Comment: header location won't work as well in this code

Comment: @Robert the header does work, the form won't work.

Comment: @jeroen it submits now, but instead of being blank it submits '1' in every field.

Comment: @KhalidAlmalki : because you applied isset function in every fields which returns true/1, that why 1 is submitting in every field. remove isset as I suggested in my ans.

Comment: @Rishi thank you, it works now!

Comment: @KhalidAlmalki it won't work because there is already content sent to browser. You will get notice "headers already sent"

Answer (score 0):

Also `isset` returns `true` or `false`

You need to Change your code like this

```
$checkTitle = isset($_POST['nM-title']) ? $_POST['nM-title'] : "";

$mNTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nM-title']);
```